# Why do Claro vendors give out already pre-registered SIM cards for free in Peru?

Tags: cellphones, peru

I read on https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Peru ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/save/https://prepaid-data-sim-card.fandom.com/wiki/Peru)):

> In spite of this, visitors can't help notice there is still a very visible black market on many market streets of Lima, Cusco and other towns for **already pre-registered SIM cards** called chips. They are sold for as low as S./5 and **Claro vendors even sell them for free**. The ambulantes (street vendors) can be easily spotted for their vests with the logos of the providers and some of them even hold up signs (see details in this report in Spanish).

Why do Claro vendors give out pre-registered SIM cards for free? Do those SIM cards have nothing by default (no text, no call, no data)?

Comment: I have no idea. But it seems likely that a) they do it because they get something out of it, which in turn suggests b) they're paid to give the cards away, or c) they get some small proportion of any text/minutes/data that's purchased for the cards they give away..

Comment: How can you sell something ‘for free’?

Comment: @Traveller One can't, of course. The page linked in the original question showed impaired English and odd word choice. I think the use of the word "sell" is a result of poor translation.